# ssis multiple column delimiter

Tags: ssis

Hi guys I am looking for some help with flat files source in data flow task or bulk mail task.  Say I have incoming flat files, I can have

a;b;c or a|b|c

is it possible to assign multiple column delimiter for the same flat file source?

I have been searching how to do it 
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

the flat file task doesn't support this. See this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7969038/set-multiple-row-delimiters-in-flat-file-connection) as reference.

Instead you could use a `script task` to determine, which delimiter is used and then forward it to the flat file task with the suitable delimiter.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to a simliar problem and ended up using [Swiss File Knife](http://stahlworks.com/dev/swiss-file-knife.html).  Just preprocess the file and have it replace commas with pipes or vice versa.  That way you only need to have one import.

You also could use a script transform in your flat file reader to use the string.split method.  I'd probably go with the SFK option though.  It's a bit more transparent, although slightly less portable.